# Pass a form object to other forms in the same page/view()

Tags: django, django-forms

How do you reference a form object that was just created above in the form validation block of a view?

If you have a shared model, with two other optionally related models:

```
class Tree(models.Model):
  type= ...
class Picture(models.Model):
  camera = ...
  tree=models.ForeignKey(Tree)
class Lumber(models.Model):
  used_to_build = ...
  tree=models.ForeignKey(Tree)
  picture=models.ForeignKey(Picture, blank=True, null=True)
class Bird(models.Model):
  species = ...
  tree=models.ForeignKey(Tree)
  picture=models.ForeignKey(Picture, blank=True, null=True)
```

You can create a Bird, and Lumber in their own views, and of course reference a specific tree.

If you have a view, and you create a form that lets you create a picture of a tree, lumber, and a bird, and you want to pass the newly created Picture to the Lumber and BirdForm, since in this case, we know which Picture the lumber and Bird are in:

```
def treeView(request):   
  #Post
    pictureForm = PictureForm(instance=tree, prefix='treeForm')
    # This is what I am trying to figuere out
    # lumberForm = LumberForm(instance=tree, picture=pictureForm.object prefix='lumberForm')
    lumberForm = LumberForm(instance=tree, prefix='lumberForm')
    birdForm = BirdForm(instance=tree, prefix='birdForm')
```

How do you pass in the actual object created to the other forms that can optionally accept the related object?  ie

```
                                                ▼ how do you pass in the form object from above?
 lumberForm = LumberForm(instance=tree, picture=pictureForm.object, prefix='lumberForm')
```

- Do you have to query it once it is saved before the next step? (seems like a race condition)
- set a try/catch?
- I tried overwriting save() in the form by returning the object, but the pictureForm is just HTML, so I don't know how to get the obj...

A relevant picture to help you smile :)
[[image: Some lumber from a tree with a(n absent) bird [1]]
Album: https://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.10101895369321847.1073741831.36619363&type=1&l=70c30792e3

Comment: I'm a little bit confused with your model forms. The `instance` argument in the constructor expects an instance of the model form. I mean, you should pass a `Picture` instance to the `PictureForm`, and not a `Tree` instance. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm not sure.   I have forms that I have used that either take another parameter, and some that use an instance that is not of the same model form and they works.   I am still trying to learn the Django-form-way of saving CRUDs.  This makes me think there is a way to pass in the object as another parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood correctly the problem you are trying to solve, but I will try to provide a solution.

I'm considering the following assumptions:

- You already have the `Tree` instance
- The `Picture`, `Lumber` and `Bird` will be associated with the same `Tree`
- The created `Picture` will be associated to the `Lumber` and the `Bird` created in the same view.

Basically what you are going to do is, wrap everything in the same database transaction and let it rain.

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def treeView(request, pk):
    tree = Tree.objects.get(pk=pk)  # you tell me how you get your tree instance

    if request.method == 'POST':
        pictureForm = PictureForm(request.POST, prefix='treeForm')
        lumberForm = LumberForm(request.POST, prefix='lumberForm')
        birdForm = BirdForm(request.POST, prefix='birdForm')

        if pictureForm.is_valid() and lumberForm.is_valid() and birdForm.is_valid():
            with transaction.atomic():
                picture = pictureForm.save(commit=False)
                picture.tree = tree
                picture.save()

                lumber = lumberForm.save(commit=False)
                lumber.tree = tree
                lumber.picture = picture
                lumber.save()

                bird = birdForm.save(commit=False)
                bird.tree = tree
                bird.picture = picture
                bird.save()
            return redirect('success_view')
    else:
        pictureForm = PictureForm(prefix='treeForm')
        lumberForm = LumberForm(prefix='lumberForm')
        birdForm = BirdForm(prefix='birdForm')

    return render(request, 'tree_form.html', {
        'tree': tree,
        'pictureForm': pictureForm,
        'lumberForm': lumberForm,
        'birdForm': birdForm
    })
```

Comment: slight modification using your suggestion, and it works for me :D   Thanks!